# В каких ветках есть локальные изменения

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

Как узнать, какие ветки содержат закоммиченные, но ещё не запушенные изменения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

примерно так:

```
$ git branch -vv
* master c488ea5 [origin/master: ahead 1, behind 1] 20160210184133
  test   ffc6775 [origin/test: ahead 1] 20160210183855
  test2  ffc6775 [origin/test2: behind 1] 20160210183855
  test3  7ff0eab 20160210184754
```

здесь мы видим, что ветки master, test и test2 «привязаны» к удалённым репозиториям (показано и имя репозитория и ветка «привязки»).

также видно, что ветки master и test отстоят на один коммит каждая «впереди» (`ahead 1`), а master и test2 «позади» (`behind 1`) от содержимого удалённого репозитория.

---

**дополнительный вопрос, поднятый в комментариях**:

> Как его сократить только до веток, у которых есть ahead/behind? И как убрать commit message из таблицы?

с помощью опций команды branch, по-моему, никак. можно «порезать» вывод чем-то внешним. например, если доступна программа [*gnu/sed*](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/):

```
$ git branch -vv | sed -rn 's/(: (ahead|behind) [0-9]+[^]]*\]).*/\1/p'
* master c488ea5 [origin/master: ahead 1, behind 1]
  test   ffc6775 [origin/test: ahead 1]
  test2  ffc6775 [origin/test2: behind 1]
```

Comment: Как его сократить только до веток, у которых есть ahead? И как убрать commit message из таблицы?

Comment: А для винды?)))

Comment: Регулярка неверная: `[origin/smth: ahead 1, behind 2]` (кстати, а что с таким делать?)

Comment: Вообще, меня интересовало, что будет пушиться при пуше всех веток. Конкретно behind меня вроде не интересует, а вот одновременно с ahead - пожалуй, да. Но я уже от этой мысли отказался - что-то там куча левых веток выплыла, которые мне уж точно пушить не надо...

Comment: @Qwertiy, я дополнил ответ. и убрал уже ненужные комментарии.

Comment: @Qwertiy когда сразу `ahead` и `behind`, тут явно `diverged` и пушить без `--force` не даст.

Answer (score 3):

`git remote show origin`, где `origin` может быть надо заменить на ваш удалённый источник, настроенный в репозитории (в который, собственно, хотите запушить).

В конце он выводит информацию о состоянии между ветками:

```
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop pushes to develop (up to date)
    master  pushes to master  (local out of date)
    dummy   pushes to dummy   (fast-forwardable)
```

- `up to date` — ветки одинаковы, на удалённом сервере всё из неё есть
- `local out of date` — изменения с сервера затянуты, но в локальной ветке их ещё нет
- `fast-forwardable` — можно пушить, удалённая ветка сделает fast-forward до вашей

Comment: Разадел `Local refs configured for 'git push':`?

Comment: @Qwertiy он самый, да.

Comment: Кажется, нет веток, которые существуют локально, но не созданы на сервере?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, только те, которые трекают ветки из `origin`. Хотя в [исходном коде гита](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d10e2cb9d0299a26f43d57dd5bdcf2b3f86a30b3/builtin/remote.c#L1032) имеются также статусы `(create)` и `(delete)`. я у себя в репозитории их не воспроизводил.